# How to let jquery get typeahead.js attribute?

Tags: jquery, twitter-typeahead

After search I want to use `jquery` to get **`typeahead.js`** search result value.

So I use `$(".tt-suggestion").click`, but it seem's not work when I click search result value.

Here's some code I have tried:

1. `$(".tt-is-under-cursor .tt-suggestion")`
2. `$(".tt-is-under-cursor")`,`$(".tt-suggestion")`

Comment: could you please share some relevant code that you have tried so far so that we can help you better.

Comment: sorry i forgot to put my code, i have been tried.